# How to test that an element comes after another element with enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

SO I have a div that I need to test. and I need to test if a ul comes right after the div. Is this possible in Enzme? I am using enzyme and jest.

Here is the div in question

```
    it('nav at bottom when bottom theme is present', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <div className="tabs tab-icon-dark-bkg-bottom">
                <div className="tab-content transition">
                </div>
                <ul className="scroll nav nav-tabs">
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
        //
        expect(wrapper.????).toBe(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.find`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) supports CSS selectors like the [*element+element*](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) selector which

> is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element

Call `.find` with `'div + ul'` to find all `ul` elements immediately following a `div`:

```
it('nav at bottom when bottom theme is present', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
      <div className="tabs tab-icon-dark-bkg-bottom">
          <div className="tab-content transition">
          </div>
          <ul className="scroll nav nav-tabs">
          </ul>
      </div>
  );
  expect(wrapper.find('div + ul').length).toBe(1);  // SUCCESS
});
```